# Changing the address of a service at run time

Tags: wcf

My Web config at Client Side like this

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.7/zfsapi/api.php" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="ZfsSoapBinding" contract="SourceAPI.ZfsSoapPort"
            name="ZfsSoapPort" />          
    </client>
```

And I chnages my address at run time like this

```
        EndpointAddress epa1 = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.7/zfsapi/api.php");
        DemoChangingAddressApi.SourceAPI.ZfsSoapPortClient oservice = new SourceAPI.ZfsSoapPortClient(binding1, epa1);
        DemoChangingAddressApi.SourceAPI.ZfsVolume[] v1 = oservice.getVolumeList();


       // or instantiate whatever other binding you're using    
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

       // define the endpoint address
        EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.8/zfsapi/api.php");

       // create your WCF client-side proxy based on those settings
       DemoChangingAddressApi.SourceAPI.ZfsSoapPortClient oservice1 = new SourceAPI.ZfsSoapPortClient(binding, epa);
       DemoChangingAddressApi.SourceAPI.ZfsVolume[] v2 = oservice1.getVolumeList();
```

when i do this i get error @  `DemoChangingAddressApi.SourceAPI.ZfsVolume[] v2 = oservice1.getVolumeList();`

Error :

> Error in deserializing body of reply
>   message for operation 'getVolumeList'.

how i can change address at runtime of service

Comment: If first call (v1) works and second doesn't then the problem is on second server. Either the configuration is different or service's operation doesn't provide same result and client cannot deserialize response.

Answer (score 0):

if you access the web.config file as a xml you always could in runtime:
Something like this:
            // in the code below I had the requirment of making copies of a website dynamically

```
        // Set the root path of the Web application that contains the
        // Web.config file that you want to access.
        string configPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appRoot"] + virtualDirectoryName + "\\";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        bool change = false;
        string configFile = Path.Combine(configPath, "web.config");
        doc.Load(configFile);

        //get root element
        System.Xml.XmlElement Root = doc.DocumentElement;
        //I have created appSettings dictionary that holds key/value pairs that wanted to update in section.
        Dictionary<string, object> appSettings = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        appSettings.Add("connString", "server=" + serverAddressAppDb +
                            "; uid=" + uidAppDb + "; pwd=" + pwdAppDb +
                            "; database=" + virtualDirectoryName + "; min pool size=1; max pool size=100;");
        appSettings.Add("applogin", urlApp + virtualDirectoryName + "/login.aspx");
        appSettings.Add("appUrl", urlApp + virtualDirectoryName);
        appSettings.Add("mailer_completeImagePath", urlApp + virtualDirectoryName + "/backgrounds/");
        appSettings.Add("mailer_pathImagesComplete", urlApp + virtualDirectoryName + "/images/");

        // Now the code below will go loop through each key/value pair under section and will compare the values in with appSettings dictionary. If it sees values are different, It will update in section.
        XmlNode appNode = Root["appSettings"];
        foreach (XmlNode node in appNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (node.Attributes != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    string key = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("key").Value;
                    string value = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("value").Value;
                    if (appSettings.ContainsKey(key) && value != appSettings[key].ToString())
                    {
                        node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("value").Value = appSettings[key].ToString();
                        change = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```